# ElasticSearch: Preference for node name?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Reading the ElasticSearch documentation, I know you can specify a preferred node ID to perform searches in, as per http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html

```
_prefer_node:xyz
```

Is there a way to pass a node NAME rather than node ID? The reason is because the node ID changes sometimes, while the name is hard coded in the config file and is static.

If not, this sounds like a very reasonable ElasticSearch enhancement.

Comment: have you tried it by name? I found another part of the api [cluster routing](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4724) that is documented to only work by ID and in fact works by both ID and name.

Comment: yep, I did try name, but it doesnt accept it.

Comment: I would post to the ES github issues with this enhancement idea, the guys over there are pretty good about cranking out good ideas and getting them into ES.